Error on terra:rasterize -not taking all point values
I am trying to generate random points on a polygon with each having a separate ID number and then converting to a raster for subsequent use in Circuitscape.   For some reason "Rasterize" function seems to change its treatment of the point values each time and some get repeated and some are lost.  Please any advice.  Thank you.  Carlos
library(terra)
library(sf)
RASTER <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, ext=c(0, 100, 0,100), crs= "EPSG:27700", vals=1) 
VECT <- vect(ext(0, 100, 0,100), crs="epsg:27700")
#plot(RASTER); lines(VECT)
POLYGON <- st_as_sf(VECT) # CONVERT TO SF
POLYGON <- st_cast(POLYGON, "MULTILINESTRING") # TO MULTIINE STRING 
POLYGON.NODES <- st_sample(POLYGON, 10, type="regular") # SAMPLE 
NODES.NUMBERS <- as.numeric(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)) # AS VECTOR 
NODES.NUMBERS
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
POLYGON.NODES <- merge(POLYGON.NODES, NODES.NUMBERS) # BECOMES DATAFRAME
POLYGON.NODES
#                         geometry  y
#1  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  1
#2  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  2
#3  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  3
#4  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  4
#5  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  5
#6  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  6
#7  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  7
#8  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  8
#9  MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (...  9
#10 MULTIPOINT ((0 32.60739), (... 10
POLYGON.NODES <- st_sf(POLYGON.NODES)# WORKS BECOMES SF MULTIPOINT OBJECT AND DF 
POLYGON.NODES <- vect(POLYGON.NODES) # BECOMES SPATVEC

And now
POLYGON.NODES.RASTER <- rasterize(POLYGON.NODES, RASTER, "y")
POLYGON.NODES.RASTER
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 100, 0, 100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        : last 
#min value   :    1 
#max value   :   10 
freq(POLYGON.NODES.RASTER) # RESULTS HAVE LOST THE SEQUENCE FROM 1 TO 10 
#  layer value count
#1     1     1     1
#2     1     3     1
#3     1     5     2
#4     1     6     1
#5     1     7     2
#6     1     8     2
#7     1    10     1
plot(POLYGON.NODES.RASTER) # SHOWS SOME WITH SAME ID



Can you please edit your question and include (as expected) a self-contained, minimal, reproducible example? That is, generate a small dataset with code or use files that ship with R (see the R help files and many questions on this site for inspiration).

Thank you - apologies - i have tried to make this entirely reproducible now with example data set - it is still providing similar output where the 1 to 10 values are not all included.

You can do
library(terra)
library(sf)
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, ext=c(0, 100, 0,100), crs= "EPSG:27700", vals=1) 
v <- vect(ext(0, 100, 0,100), crs="epsg:27700") |> as.lines()
nodes <- st_sample(st_as_sf(v), 10, type="regular") 
# disaggregate to go from multipoint to point
v <- disagg(vect(nodes))  
v$ID <- 1:10

pr <- rasterize(v, r, "ID")
plot(pr, type="classes"); text(pr, halo=T)

The object you create for rasterizing is SpatVector of 10 multipoint geometries of 10 points each.

Thank you.  I truly appreciate your time and consideration on this.  This is working now and providing great flexiblity.
